# Programa em Java para inserir limite inferior e superior e retornar a soma dos números pares do intervalo

Tags: java

Estou tendo problemas pra fazer esse código funcionar corretamente. O objetivo é somar todos os números pares de um intervalo fornecido (limite inferior e superior), porém não está retornando o resultado correto usando o `for`.

Por exemplo, se eu inserir: Limite inferior (ltinf) = 0 e Limite Superior (ltsup)
 = 5, o programa retorna o valor 12 e não a soma 2+4 = 6.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz com esse problema?

```
package ps1ex3matheusportugal;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PS1EX3MatheusPortugal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int ltsup = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o limite superior: "));
        int ltinf = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insira o limite inferior: "));

        if (ltsup < ltinf){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O valor do limite inferior deve ser menor que o limite superior");
        }
        else if (ltsup > ltinf){
            int cont, somapar = ltinf;
            for (cont = ltinf; cont <= ltsup; cont++){
                if (cont % 2 == 1){
                    cont++;
                    somapar = somapar + 2;
                }
                else{
                    for (cont = ltinf; cont <= ltsup; cont++){
                        somapar = somapar + 2;
                    }
                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A soma de todos os números dentro do intervalo inserido é: " + somapar);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (cont = ltinf; cont <= ltsup; cont++){
    if (cont % 2 == 1){
        cont++;
        somapar = somapar + 2;
    }
    else{
        for (cont = ltinf; cont <= ltsup; cont++){
            somapar = somapar + 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Esta lógica está confusa, tem até um for dentro do else. Não consigo nem mesmo dizer como arrumar ela, o que posso sugerir é reformular o código.

```
int somapar = 0;
for (int cont = ltinf; cont <= ltsup; cont++) {
    if (cont % 2 == 0){
        somapar += cont;
    }
}
```

Você também pode incrementar o contador de dois em dois, garantindo que o contador sempre será par:

```
int somapar = 0;
if (ltinf % 2 != 0) {
    ltinf++;
}
for (int cont = ltinf; cont <= ltsup; cont += 2) {
    somapar += cont;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, utilizei a segunda lógica, incrementando de dois em dois e resolveu o problema!